Android app Not to share cookies/session between two webviews, app developed using Kotlin
I am building one app that will open 2 webviews side by side, it's working. But I want cookies should not be shared across each other, I mean context should be independent.
Please find below code snippet, I tried different approaches with help of ChatGPT :) , not working ... New to Android development.... guide here to solve
package com.example.twowebviews

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.CookieManager
import android.webkit.WebSettings
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var webView1: WebView
    lateinit var webView2: WebView
    lateinit var swipeRefresh1: SwipeRefreshLayout
    lateinit var swipeRefresh2: SwipeRefreshLayout
    lateinit var urlBar1: EditText
    lateinit var urlBar2: EditText
    lateinit var refreshButton1: Button
    lateinit var refreshButton2: Button
    private val cookieManager1 = CookieManager.getInstance()
    private val cookieManager2 = CookieManager.getInstance()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Initialize WebViews and UI components
        webView1 = findViewById(R.id.webview_1)
        webView2 = findViewById(R.id.webview_2)
        swipeRefresh1 = findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_1)
        swipeRefresh2 = findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_2)
        urlBar1 = findViewById(R.id.url_bar_1)
        urlBar2 = findViewById(R.id.url_bar_2)
        refreshButton1 = findViewById(R.id.refresh_button_1)
        refreshButton2 = findViewById(R.id.refresh_button_2)

        // Configure WebView settings
        configureWebView(webView1)
        configureWebView(webView2)

        // Set initial URLs
        loadUrlInWebView(webView1, "https://platform.dev.testurl.com")
        loadUrlInWebView(webView2, "https://platform.dev.testurl.com")

        // Handle pull-to-refresh
        swipeRefresh1.setOnRefreshListener {
            webView1.reload()
            swipeRefresh1.isRefreshing = false
        }

        swipeRefresh2.setOnRefreshListener {
            webView2.reload()
            swipeRefresh2.isRefreshing = false
        }

        // Handle refresh button clicks
        refreshButton1.setOnClickListener {
            webView1.reload()
        }

        refreshButton2.setOnClickListener {
            webView2.reload()
        }

        // Handle URL changes
        urlBar1.setOnEditorActionListener { _, _, _ ->
            loadUrlInWebView(webView1, urlBar1.text.toString())
            true
        }

        urlBar2.setOnEditorActionListener { _, _, _ ->
            loadUrlInWebView(webView2, urlBar2.text.toString())
            true
        }
    }
    private fun createCustomContext(base: Context, themeResId: Int): Context {
        return ContextThemeWrapper(base, themeResId)
    }
    private fun configureWebView(webView: WebView) {
        // Create a new CookieManager instance
        val cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance()
        cookieManager.removeAllCookies(null) // Clear cookies to start fresh

        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true)
        cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true)
        webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()  // Ensures links open within the WebView
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true  // Enable JavaScript support if needed
        // Enable localStorage
        webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
//        val webSettings: WebSettings = webView.settings
        webView.settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT // Enable default cache mode
        // Clear any existing cache and cookies
        webView.clearCache(true)
        webView.clearHistory()

    }

    private fun loadUrlInWebView(webView: WebView, url: String) {
        if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")) {
            webView.loadUrl("https://$url")
        } else {
            webView.loadUrl(url)
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        // Clean up WebViews
        webView1.destroy()
        webView2.destroy()
    }
}

